# Extract a string that is the difference between two other strings in PHP

Tags: php, string

I wanted to extract sting that is the difference between two strings using native PHP functions.

Consider my code:

```
$a = 'ABC';
$b = 'ABCDEF';
$al = strlen($a);
$bl = strlen($b);
$d = $bl - $al;

$r = substr($b, -$d);

echo $r; // Returns 'DEF'
```

This seems to be a lot of steps for this simple operation. Is there a more straigtforward way to achieve this?

Comment: Hmm, so if for example, `$a = "hello";` and `$b = "111hello000";`, then it should return `111000`? Why can't you just `str_replace($a, '', $b);`?

Comment: your above code wouldn't work if `$a` was `bcd`.  Try using [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
$a = 'ABC';
$b = 'ABCDEF';
echo str_replace($a, '', $b);
```

Comment: I belive this is the best way to go around it since it would return the difference from the beginning and end of the longer string (the common part is somwhere in the middle). Thanks!

Comment: You just have to add some checks if needed. :)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to the extra string length calls. you simply request the substr to start from the point of the $a length.

```
$r = substr($b, $strlen($a))
```

Comment: This is a much better, simplified version of what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = 'ABC';
$b = 'ABCDEF';
$al = strlen($a);
$bl = strlen($b);
if($bl >= $al){
  $r = str_replace($a,'',$b);
}else{
  $r = str_replace($b,'',$a);
}
echo $r;
```

That way you check which string is longer and remove the shorter string from the longer one.